# I haven't asked a question in ages yet i still get barred from asking any new questions

Tags: support

Yesterday i've asked a question that wasn't received badly. In total it has received +1 vote. I'm trying to start a new question but i can't. Instead of the question form the following text appears:

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
> break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been
> received very well by the community.

I did **not** ask 4 questions recently. I may have asked 3 questions in the past (which are all deleted apparently) but that must have been a very long time ago. I do not want to wait 3 days just because i've asked some bad questions a year or so ago. I am not a novice stack exchange user either. I've got 4866 points on stack overflow so i know how to make a good question. Could someone please remove this limitation from my account?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked questions recently.

You have asked a total of 6 questions. One on [December 21, 2018 (deleted)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/384426/is-there-an-out-of-the-box-solution-for-displaying-text-differences-in-java), one on [January 9, 2019 (deleted)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/385212/retrieving-user-likes-per-case-versus-retrieving-all-likes-made-and-storing-them). Then, there was a pause and questions were asked on [September 7, 2021 (deleted)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431724/how-long-does-it-generally-take-for-an-opened-hibernate-issue-to-be-resolved), [September 9, 2021 (deleted)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431771/how-do-you-mention-someone-on-github-whose-name-consists-of-two-parts-divided-by), [December 16, 2021 (deleted)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/435382/what-was-the-reasoning-behind-allowing-log4j2-to-resolve-ldap-addresses), and [January 31, 2021](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436379/semantic-versioning-for-spa-applications-with-a-restful-backend).

Of the questions, all but one have a negative score. The net score for all of the questions is -15.

I'm not sure what the timeframe for "recently" is, but I don't think that the span of a few months is unreasonable for "recently".

The limitations that you are running into are automatic slowdowns and blocks. The fact that you have been a long-time user of the network and have a positive reputation on Stack Overflow has no bearing on your participation here. The number of negatively scored and deleted questions indicates that you may not have a good understanding of this community's scope and expectations for questions.

I would recommend spending some time to review [our Help Center](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/help), other questions here on Meta, and some of the top questions here to get a better understanding of this community and what is considered a good question here. Our scope, standards, and expectations are different than Stack Overflow and even other sites in the SE network.